# What makes a private IP address not routable?

Tags: networking, routing, ipv4

I understand that private addresses such as `10.0.0.0/8`,`172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16` are not routable. However, what exactly is stopping these addresses from being routable? Do ISPs implement ACLs that prevent these networks from routing or is it something higher up?

Also, is it IANA that created this design?

Comment: Is there an implied question of "Is it GUARANTEED they won't be routed publicly, and is anyone still routing the publicly acting in error?"?

Comment: As for your last question: the [IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force) defined them for IANA to be excluded from the public address-space. [RFC1918 for IPv4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) and [RFC4193 for IPv6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193)

Comment: Minor correction to the OP: RFC1918 defines 172.16.0.0/12, not /16.

Comment: ISPs do implement ACLs to drop these packets. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogon_filtering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_packet

Comment: Routers in the default-free zone drop such packets as they have no route for them.

Comment: Of course they are routable.  Routers take a message from your public external address and "route" it to an internal private address.  Recommend you look up the basics of Network Address Translation.

Comment: Lakey, they are not routable on the public web. Hence why Nat is required and is used to conserve IP addresses.. I am in a Cisco class and my professor could not answer this question so that is why I am posting it here.

Comment: Also, I should have clarified that private addresses are routable in a private network but not a public network.

Comment: I believe they're unroutable on the public Internet simply because nobody gets allocated those addresses. i.e. the addresses aren't used.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Private IP addresses **are** routable, albeit they are not *publicly* routed. Basically, a router will route a private address to private/internal LAN, rather than to the internet.

To expand my answer: a router *can* route a private address to the public side, via its default gateway. However, the packet will be "lost" in transit due to other routers dropping it, or due to packet's TTL reaching 0.

For example, give a look at this (partially obfuscated) `traceroute -I -n 192.168.200.1`:

```
[root@myhost ~]# traceroute -I -n 192.168.200.1
traceroute to 192.168.200.1 (192.168.200.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  x.x.x.x  0.851 ms  0.841 ms  0.818 ms
 2  6x.xx.xx.xx  0.791 ms  0.791 ms  0.849 ms
 3  15x.xx.xx.xx  1.350 ms  1.347 ms  1.373 ms
 4  15x.x.xx.xx  1.446 ms  1.435 ms  1.428 ms
 5  151.6.68.20  2.272 ms  2.266 ms  2.251 ms
 6  151.6.0.91  8.818 ms  8.256 ms  8.326 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
...
...
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

As you can see, the packet *is* routed to the public internet via the machine's default gateway. However, it is dropped during the transit and never reaches any proper destination.

After all, private IPs/classes are (by definition) overlapped between customer, so on which of the thousands 192.168.200.x/24 networks should be routed this packet?

An interesting side note: internet providers often uses private addresses for their internal routing. If, for example, a private 192.168.200.x/24 classes is used for internal routing, the first router/machine with IP 192.168.200.1 *will* receive but drop the packet, because it was unsolicited. ICMP are an interesting exception, as router/machines generally replies to unsolicited PINGs. This means you sometime can use private address scans to map your ISP private network.

Comment: So basically, if the IP address starts with 10, 172.16-31, or 192.168, then the router should be configured to only send them through the internal LAN network, rather than out to the external internet (in an Enterprise, generally through the external gateway). You can read up on these 'private networks' here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: It's actually not uncommon to route private RFC1918 addresses (192.168, 172.16, 10) whenever you make a routed private network.

Comment: @Bruno not necessarily. A route *can* route a private address on the public side to its default gateway, but other routers will finally drop the packets or route it in a loop (and the packet will be discarded when its TTL reaches 0).

Comment: Do the ISP's main routers even *have* a default gateway? What would it be?

Comment: Generally, yes. After all, a ISP needs to route packets intended for other ISPs...

Answer (score 11):

Private IP addresses (as per RFC 1918) are very much routable, just not on the public Internet.

Usually, private IP addresses are filtered by the ISP. Your access router should also be configured to not make them leak.

Private IP addresses can't be used on the Internet because *anyone could be using them*. There are probably many million devices using 192.168.1.1 privately - which one is an Internet router supposed to send the packet?

*Zeroconf* addresses (169.254.0.0/16) are actually not routable at all. These can be used anywhere in an ad-hoc fashion but they can't access the Internet or any subnet but their local one. They can't be routed because they can only be valid inside the broadcast domain where each device can select an unused address by itself. By definition, zeroconf has no management instance like a DHCP server.

Answer (score 6):

**However, what exactly is stopping these addresses from being routable?**

Accepted standards that are enforced by entities communicating.  These are enforced in software, hardware, and configurations.

**Do ISPs implement ACLs that prevent these networks from routing or is it something higher up?**

They can but what is really being stopped is merely an invalid translation that does not follow standards.

If you are like most home users, you have one IP address assigned to you as a public IP address.  In order for traffic from all of your connected devices to communicate, the router performs translation of those internal IP addresses using NAT (network address translation) or PAT (port address translation).

Basically, your router remembers which internal IP addresses in your LAN (local area network) started a session reaching outside of your LAN, through the router, and out the WAN (wide area network) interface.  When data exits the router it contains that single IP address assigned to you as the source IP.  When it enters, the packet contains the same address as the destination IP.  The router decides then where it gets directed from there.

To the outside, you have only one single IP address which is actually the IP of the router.  The router is able to track those sessions and determine which traffic belongs to each internal IP address on it's LAN and directs that traffic accordingly.  It's a complex management process but the idea is actually quite simple once you understand that everything is being translated at each router.

Furthermore, most home routers have switching ports, whereby the traffic is delivered via MAC address, not IP address.  The source MAC address in the packet remains the same until it hits a router.  The router strips that source MAC address and inserts the MAC address of it's own WAN interface.

**Also, is it IANA that created this design?**

These standards were not originally designed by IANA.  Today, although they take the lead on setting standards, they certainly do not enforce them through any means of law.  They are standards that are enforced through consensus.   Search RFC 791.

They have "authority" to to the extent that everyone is willing to adhere to them.  It is completely possible to defy these standards but you will eventually run into an ISP somewhere along the path that will demand that you do adhere or they will drop your traffic.

I hope that helps..

Comment: I think every word of this hits the nail on the head, as pertaining to the OP's specific question. The other answers are factually correct but I'm not sure they address the OP's specific confusion as directly as they could. The key point is: _convention and the fact that most people want to abide by it_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : That is basically covered by the very first non-quoted word in this answer, which would not be strictly necessary... The word emphasizes the point you make.  Although, I do agree that your italicized text does make the point better.

Comment: @TOOGAM: Yep I'm just re-inforcing it. As I said, I think this answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

As a point of clarification from the other answers, private IP address ranges *that you are using locally* do not route to the Internet because they have their own explicit entries in the routing table.  Here's my route table from my desktop at home, for example:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.104 metric 1024 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-90a372f4b373 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104 
192.168.1.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 1024
```

Note the `172.17.0.0/16` and `172.18.0.0/16`.  Packets to these networks will go straight to my docker bridges, without ever leaving my computer, because they have a specific entry in my route table.  The `192.168.1.0/24` entry explicitly says traffic to that network will go out the `enp5s0` interface.  My router's route table will have a similar entry that will send all traffic for that private network out the interface my desktop is connected to.

It's only packets for networks that aren't explicitly in the table that will go to the default route.  You can explicitly mark a network as unreachable by:

```
$ ip route add unreachable 10.0.0.0/8
```

This changes my route table to:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.104 metric 1024 
unreachable 10.0.0.0/8 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-90a372f4b373 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.104 
192.168.1.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.104 metric 1024
```

Now, my desktop won't even try to ask the default gateway about addresses in that range.  Lookups for that address immediately return "No route to host."

```
$ traceroute 10.0.0.1
traceroute to 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
connect: No route to host
```

Packets for unreachable networks that aren't explicitly *marked* as unreachable in the route table will just keep being forwarded via the default routes, until the packet either reaches a router that explicitly knows the network is unreachable, or the TTL expires.